# Is it possible for Gammu SMSD queue out sms when using null backend?

Tags: linux, sms

I have an application that send out sms using gammu smsd.
My application don't need to save the sms for each sent message or received or error and on outbox, so I configure gammu-smsd with null backend.

Is it possible for gammu-smsd queue sms for sending when I use the null backend? I don't need any retry capability for sms that is not sent on the first try or to resume sending sms when I restart gammu-smsd daemon.

Thanks.